# C# sqlite-net-sqlcipher Get Table with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm in trouble with SQLChiper (i'm using NuGet package sqlite-net-sqlcipher) ..
I have a database generated by another program with a table which I know the name "JobProduction" but not the Columns because is the customer database (i only know that are all varchars and the mcp_id is the PrimaryKey)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SQLiteConnectionString options =
                new("dbname.sqlite", true, "password");

        SQLiteConnection Connection = new(options);

        TableMapping table = Connection.GetMapping<JobProduction>();
        var data = Connection.Query(table, $"SELECT * FROM JobProduction Where mcp_id='43';");

        Connection.Close();
    }

    [Table("JobProduction")]
    public class JobProduction
    {
        // Dynamic columns ??
    }
```

the variable data will contain the class without columns..

i know i can get columns info with

```
List<SQLiteConnection.ColumnInfo> columns = Connection.GetTableInfo("JobProduction");
```

But how i can create dinamically class properties??
Connection.TableMappings is empty too.. I can see the table with SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable tool..

Someone has a solution or i'm trying to do something impossible??
i cant query directly the database.. every function of the SQLiteConnection want the Class type or the TableMapping..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it is impossible, although I do think that the choice of DB type is less than optimal. How much variance do you expect in table schemas of that table (or tables)? Are only a small fixed selection of columns of interest to you or do you need to make them all available through your application?

Comment: hello @Fildor, i dont know the number of the columns.. and i need them all

Comment: Is considering something like a Document DB an option or are you locked-in to SQLite?

Comment: I could change database even if it would be better to continue with SQLite if there was a solution (no Access) .. do you have any advice?

Comment: Not from the top of my head. I would need to try some things myself ... for now, I upvote to attract more people to the question.

Comment: thank you very much